# Find all homomorphisms between $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

I want to find all homomorphisms $ \phi: \mathbb{Z}_n \to \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$. I have observed so far that $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is generated by $1$, i.e. $ \mathbb{Z}_n = \langle 1 \rangle$. I have also considered that $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\} = \langle 1 \rangle$.

So far, then I surmise that our homormophism $\phi$ must satisfy $\phi(1) = 1$.

We also observe that $n \cdot 1  = 0 \mod n$ for $\mathbb{Z}_n$. So this must mean that the homormophism $\phi$ must satisfy

$$\phi(n \cdot 1)  = \phi(0) = \phi(n) \phi(1) $$

---

What other sorts of properties/relations must $\phi$ satisfy?

NOTE: I have read the other posts regarding "finding all homormorphisms between..." and they either deal with two finite groups or deal with symmetric/dihedral groups, so please do not link them in the comments.

Comment: What does $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}=<1>$ mean?  And why should $\phi(1)=1$?

Comment: I think you mean that $\phi(0)=1$, since $0$ is the identity in $(\mathbb{Z}_n,+)$.

Comment: Also, a hom $\phi: \mathbb{Z}_n \to G$ is solely determined by the value of $\phi(1)$.  Maybe this is what you wanted to use.

Comment: @lulu it means that $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ is generated by $1$

Comment: But that is clearly false.

Comment: @EmilyBurkenhamen  but that is false.  How do you get $1+i$ from $1$?

Comment: My bad, I was confusing $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ with the vector space $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Indeed, $1$ is the identity element for the multiplicative group of the non-zero complex numbers, usually written $\mathbb C^*$.  Hence, your homomorphism must satisfy $\phi(0)=1$, but there is no need for it to satisfy $\phi(1)=1$.

Comment: @lulu I see. So what do we make of the fact that $\phi(0) = \phi(n \cdot 1) = \phi(n)\phi(1) = 1?$

Comment: You are forgetting that the operation in $\mathbb Z_n$ is addition.  Consider $n=2$.  Then it is true that $1+1\equiv 0\pmod 2$.  Thus $1=\phi(0)=\phi(1+1)=\phi(1)\times \phi(1)=\phi(1)^2$.  So...$\phi(1)\in \{\pm 1\}$.